# error (1, -2147483648) on Android

Tags: android

Does anybody know the meaning of this error?

```
 VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideo);    
 Intent videoint=getIntent();    
 String url =  videoint.getStringExtra("url"); //The url pointing to the mp4     
 video.setVideoPath(url);     
 video.requestFocus();     
 video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));     
 video.start();
```

The manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Can you give a little more information? Where do you see this error? At what point does it occur?

Comment: Please please post as much info as you can, rather than resorting to a guessing game in trying to work out what is it about!!!

Comment: I included the code that produced the error in my edit. Thanks guys.

Comment: What is the permissions in your manifest?

Comment: Here it is                                                     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error code. In my case the error is generated because the video encoding is not supported by android. Just try to re-encode your video.

this page should help: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same error on Froyo & Gingerbread. In higher Androids the same video played well. Finally after a lot of research, tried changing the Https Url to Http Url
& Bingo. It resolved my issue. I was using amazon S3 server so that simply replacing the "https" in url with "http" was sufficient.

```
  videoUrl= videoUrl.replaceFirst("https", "http");
```

PS: For supporting older versions if you are using H.264 make sure videos are Baseline encoded.

Comment: the problem was https in my case too, https is not supported before 3.1 http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Amazing fix! Any ideas how to make sure the video is Baseline encoded?

Comment: You need to cross check that with your encoding utility. In case if you are using a streaming service there might be an option(in some servers to support phones) to chose encoding profile where in you can set it baseline.

Comment: worked for me too!! thanks a lot :) btw i am also using amazon s3 as a data source

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial on how to use the [VideoView](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-videoview-example) that will shed light on your issue.

I think you have left out a line or two:

```
mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
video.setVideoURI(video);
```

Adapt it to suit your code where applicable. The layout could be missing...

Comment: I also got the error 'attempt to call getduration without a valid mediaplayer'. Any idea?