# Video Streaming with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, video, streaming

I try to stream video with this link with code below :

```
VideoView mVideoView;
MediaController mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);        
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://ref10.vn.aditmedia.net:8080/video?channel=1004&token=6436488"));
mVideoView.start();
```

But i can't stream this video althought i try this link on Windows Media Player and it can stream this video. Anyone help me!

Thanks

Comment: What format is the video? Android can only handle [certain formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Comment: are the spaces in the URL on purpose?

Comment: @koljaTM Apologies, I think that was my edit

Comment: This URL run good in another app in android, i just test but with my code it doesn't @_@

Comment: Perhaps, but **what** format is the video? What logcat output do you see? Does the device display a dialog saying 'Sorry this video cannot be played' or something else?

Comment: Yup! It show "Sorry this video cannot be played". Log cat show this :01-15 21:07:49.101: V/MediaPlayer(16066): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
01-15 21:07:49.101: E/MediaPlayer(16066): error (1, -2147483648)
01-15 21:07:49.101: V/MediaPlayer(16066): callback application
01-15 21:07:49.101: V/MediaPlayer(16066): back from callback
01-15 21:07:49.101: E/MediaPlayer(16066): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-15 21:07:49.101: D/VideoView(16066): Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: Thanks i've fixed this bug, this video type is in support by android 4.1 or above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your URL,remove spaces between `http://ref10.vn.aditmedia.net:8080/video?` and `channel=1004&token=6436488`

Comment: I determine my URL but there is no space! I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Can you try mVideoView.setVideoPath("http://ref10.vn.aditmedia.net:8080/video?channel=1004&token=6436488") instead of mVideoView.setVideoURI("") and provide a cat log please.

Comment: Here is my log cat:01-15 21:07:49.101: V/MediaPlayer(16066): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
01-15 21:07:49.101: E/MediaPlayer(16066): error (1, -2147483648)
01-15 21:07:49.101: V/MediaPlayer(16066): callback application
01-15 21:07:49.101: V/MediaPlayer(16066): back from callback
01-15 21:07:49.101: E/MediaPlayer(16066): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-15 21:07:49.101: D/VideoView(16066): Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711081/error-1-2147483648-on-android