# How to play video in android 4.0 and above

Tags: android

Bs"d
Hi everybody
I need to play a video
I have created an VideoView that takes uri parameter
and plays it
In Galaxy s2 and Galaxy s1 it works good but in Galaxy s3
it doesn't play
This is my source code

```
   video=new VideoView(this);
 MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
 video.setMediaController(mc);
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);    
     video.setVideoURI(uri);
     video.requestFocus();
     setContentView(video);
     video.start();
```

Comment: paste your logs here.

Comment: 03-14 12:22:31.745: E/MediaPlayer(21472): Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: Bs"d
Probably it is problem of not supported file
I have tried to use Media file in type m3u8 and it worked
In the link below it possible to see
[Look at the first answer of this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711081/error-1-2147483648-on-android?rq=1