# Android Media Player send a myterious request

Tags: php, android, apache, http, media-player

I test an Android application which plays videos.
The problem is the video play fail with an unknown error:

```
MediaPlayer(20533): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

The application code :

```
// Place the video view.
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

// Retrieve the video path.
path = getIntent().getStringExtra(PATH);
Log.i(TAG, "Play the file : " + path);

// Set the video to play.
mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
mVideoView.requestFocus();
// Start the video play.
mVideoView.start();
```

The web server which serves the video is an Apache2 with PHP 5.

HTTP requests:

The first:

```
GET /.../hsf6bfs9/android.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.2.2)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 16:57:42 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: public
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="android.mp4"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 0-5245532/5245533
Content-Length: 5245533
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

The second:

```
GET /.../hsf6bfs9/android.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.2.2)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Range: bytes=4927056-

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 16:57:45 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Mod-H264-Streaming: version=2.2.7
Content-Length: 318511
Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 16:57:43 GMT
ETag: "36bc00b-500a5d-4de56facaefc0;5245567"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 4927056-5245566/5245567
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

And the final one before the fail:

```
GET /.../hsf6bfs9/android.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.2.2)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Range: bytes=3591808430-

HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable
Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 16:57:47 GMT
Server: Apache
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Requested Range Not Satisfiable</h1>
<p>None of the range-specifier values in the Range
request-header field overlap the current extent
of the selected resource.</p>
</body></html>
```

Logs found:

```
06-05 10:23:06.577: I/NuCachedSource2(161): new range: offset= 4927056
06-05 10:23:07.618: I/NuCachedSource2(161): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
06-05 10:23:07.618: I/NuCachedSource2(161): new range: offset= 3591808430
06-05 10:23:07.618: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(161): Reconnecting...
06-05 10:23:07.638: D/overlay(158): Unset pipe=RGB1 dpy=0; 
06-05 10:23:07.788: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(161): We requested a content range, but server didn't support that. (responded with 416)
06-05 10:23:07.788: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(161): Reconnect failed w/ err 0xffffffe0
06-05 10:23:07.788: E/MediaPlayer(19641): error (1, -2147483648)
```

Do you have an idea of the problem ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html), this error is thrown with the constant `USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE`.

> Suggests using the default stream type. This may not be used in all
>   places a stream type is needed.
>
> Constant Value: -2147483648 (0x80000000)

May [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995668/mediaplayer-error-when-attempt-to-play-from-a-stream) answer help. Maybe the mediaPlayer didn't have the right permissions to play this file so you could check [this](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2988).

Finally you could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711081/error-1-2147483648-on-android) which suggests that the video encoding isn't supported by Android.

Hope this helps =)